# Running rendering script on remote computer: Exception_Access_Violation (Win32 Error 127)

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, blend-files

for each request getting, I am calling **blender with a blend-script** by the python call **subprocess.run**, in order to render an image of a stl-file. This works normally very well.

Unfortunately, I am sporadically hanging in a **deathlock**. Then, I see on the console the following error message, after the blender render function for **eevee**

bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True, animation=False,write_still=True)

was called.

**Warning! Using result of ChoosePixelFormat.
Win32 Error# (127): The specified procedure could not be found.
Error : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x0000000000000000**

Thanks to scurest post below, I think the issue is cause by closing the remote session. It seems that blender loses the right to access some dll's or so, as mentioned in the post of the link.
Does anyone has an idea how to get a blender rendering script running on a remote computer without having a remote session allways active? This must be possible, or?

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T84675 https://developer.blender.org/T92506

Comment: Hi scurest, thank you for your reply. With your link I was able to reproduce the issue. As long the remote connection is on, it works fine. Clossing the remote connection causes the issue. As mentioned in a sublink: "On Windows only system processes and services run in Session 0.  The user logs on to Session 1." So, for my understanding, when I am closing the connection, blender is loosing the permission to access some dll? And running the script as a service will not help, because of Session 0 and no Displaymanager, or? If I am correct, a user must always logged in.

Comment: How I can run my blender script with a closed remote connection? There must be a way, or I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It must connected to some user in order to have the graphic interface avaiable. It is possible configure a service or a scheduled task started under a user account. There also exist something like autologon (not nice).